# Sift through Azure AD with ADSI Edit

Tags: azure, active-directory

I am part of a Office 365 organization, let's assume it's `fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com`. I have ADSI Edit available locally. (How) Can I connect to the Azure AD of my O365 organization, to have a look at the data stored therein?

I tried the following ADSI Edit settings:

```
Name: RootDSE
Path: LDAP://fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com/RootDSE

Connection point

( ) Select or type a Distinguished Name or Name Context
(o) Select a Well Known Naming Context: RootDSE

Select or type a domain or server ( Server | Domain [:Port])
fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com
```

This throws "The server is not operational".

I also tried to get the AD server name via Exchange EWS Managed API AutoDiscoverService GetUserSettings:

```
AutodiscoverService ads = new AutodiscoverService();
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });
ads.Credentials = new WebCredentials(username, password); ;
ads.TraceListener = new TraceListener(dbg, ads);
ads.RedirectionUrlValidationCallback = new AutodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });
        CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;
        int timeOut = 30000; // ms
        var task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ads.GetUserSettings(mail.ToString(), UserSettingName.ActiveDirectoryServer), token);
        if (!task.Wait(timeOut, token))
            throw new TimeoutException("Timeout during Exchange AutoDiscover");
var serverDNS = task.Result.Settings[UserSettingName.ActiveDirectoryServer].ToString();
```

which, when  throws

```
<Message>Fehler</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>There are no user settings to return.</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverResponseException
</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
bei Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverRequest.InternalExecute()  
bei Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.InternalGetUserSettings(List`1 smtpAddresses, List`1 settings, Nullable`1 requestedVersion, Uri& autodiscoverUrl)  
bei Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.GetSettings[TGetSettingsResponseCollection,TSettingName](List`1 identities, List`1 settings, Nullable`1 requestedVersion, GetSettingsMethod`2 getSettingsMethod, Func`1 getDomainMethod)  
bei Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.GetUserSettings(List`1 smtpAddresses, List`1 settings)  
bei Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.InternalGetSoapUserSettings(String smtpAddress, List`1 requestedSettings)  
bei Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.GetUserSettings(String userSmtpAddress, UserSettingName[] userSettingNames)  
bei System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()  
bei System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
</StackTrace>
```

Can I somehow look at my organization's Azure AD from here, or can I only access it from an Azure VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that any of the [authentication protocols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151124.aspx) that Azure Active Directory (AAD) supports  are supported by ADSI Edit. ADSI Edit isn't really meant to administer AAD.  Instead it can view and administer on-premise AD, which is really a different thing altogether.

You might choose to build an app that mimics ADSI Edit functionality.  If you were to do that, you'd probably use tools like the [Azure AD Authentication Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj573266.aspx) (Windows only) and the [Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/api-catalog) (any platform) to query an Azure AD tenant.

Comment: Azure AD and On-Premise AD are entirely different? So, when I have an app that uses code to access the on-premise AD, and install such an app in an Azure VM, that app would fail to work with Azure AD?

Comment: Yes.  You can put a traditional AD server in the cloud and join your Azure VMs to it.  Your code would work then.  But an Azure VM doesn't really have any interaction at all with Azure AD, unless you write some app that runs on that VM that does AAD authentication or something,  Your Azure VM isn't domain-joined to Azure AD, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD doesn't support LDAP which is what ADSI Edit is trying to use. In fact it doesn't speak any of the protocols your on-prem AD speaks today. You could use the Graph Explorer as a loose replacement - https://graphexplorer.cloudapp.net/

Comment: So, when I have an app that uses code like `new DirectoryEntry("GC://")` to access the on-premise AD, and install such an app in an Azure VM, that app would fail to work with Azure AD?